Extended Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation
I have this follow-up question. I have a nurse scheduling problem with the goal of minimizing the length of stay of all patients over the planning horizon. For details see here:   Now I added the variable $m_{ij}$, which indicates if a patient $i$ is treated by a nurse $j$. Now I added the constraints (3) and (4) to ensure that each patient is only treated by one nurse. This is extended model:
\begin{align}
\min \quad & \sum_{i \in I} f_i \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & g_{ik} = \sum_{j \in J} a_{ijk} + b_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{2}\\
& a_{ijk}\leq m_{ij} &\forall i \in I, j\in J, k\in K\tag{3}\\
&\sum_{j\in J} m_{ij} = 1&\forall i\in I\tag{4}\\
& \sum_{i \in I} a_{ijk} \leq Max_j & \forall j \in J, k \in K \tag{5}\\
& \sum_{j \in J} c_{ij} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{6}\\
& f_i = \sum_{k \in K} e_{ik} \cdot k - Entry_i + 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{7}\\
& \sum_{j \in J} a_{ij,Entry_i} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{8}\\
& \sum_{k \in K} e_{ik} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{9}\\
& R_i \cdot d_{ik} \leq \sum_{j \in J} \sum_{m=1}^k a_{ijm} + E_{app} \sum_{m=1}^k b_{im} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{10}\\
& e_{ik} \leq d_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K\tag{11} \\
& e_{ik} \leq \sum_{j \in J} a_{ijk} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{12}\\
& d_{ik} \geq E_{min} \cdot b_{ik} & \forall i \in I, k \in K \tag{13}\\
& g_{ik} = 0 & \forall i \in I, k < Entry_i \tag{14}\\
& g_{i,Entry_i} = 1 & \forall i \in I \tag{15}
\end{align}
@RobPratt came up with this decomposition, but now I was wondering how to deal with the new constraints (3) and (4), specifically how to model the new constraints in the MP and how to model the objective function in the SP.
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_i \sum_p f_i^p \lambda_{ip} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \sum_p a_{ijk}^p \lambda_{ip} &\le \text{Max}_j &&\forall j,k &&(\text{$\pi_{jk} \le 0$})\\
&&\sum_p \lambda_{ip} &= 1 &&\forall i &&(\text{$\mu_i$ free})\\
&&\lambda_{ip} &\in\mathbb{Z}^+ &&\forall i,p
\end{align}
SP:
$$f_i - \sum_j \sum_k \pi_{jk} a_{ijk} - \mu_i$$
subject to (2) and (6) through (15).

Constraint (5) is the only one that involves more than one $i$ at a time, so it is natural to decompose by $i$. Your master problem and subproblem objective are correct. All constraints other than (5) go in the subproblems (one subproblem for each $i$).

Thank you at @RobPratt. May i ask you, why in this case you dont include constraint (3) into the subproblem, as you indicated in your anwser prior?

I do include (3), because all variables have an $i$ index, in subproblem $i$.

sorry i was meant to say "in the MP", as you did in the answer before.

In the linked question, you had $a_{ijk} \le m_{jk}$, which does not have the property that all variables have an $i$ index, so I treated those constraints as complicating/linking.
